# How to change the format for values in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to change the format for values in a column in a dataframe. If I have a dataframe in that format:

df =

```
sector       funding_total_usd

1                 NaN

2               10,00,000

3               3,90,000

4               34,06,159

5              2,17,50,000

6               20,00,000
```

How to change it to that format:

df =

```
sector       funding_total_usd

1                 NaN

2               10000.00

3               3900.00

4               34061.59

5              217500.00

6               20000.00
```

This is my code:

```
for row in df['funding_total_usd']:

    dt1 = row.replace (',','')

    print (dt1)
```

This is the error that I got "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'"

I need really to your help in how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way to get the decimal places:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame({'funding_total_usd': [np.nan, 1000000, 390000, 3406159,21750000,2000000]})

print(df)
df['funding_total_usd'] /= 100
print(df)

   funding_total_usd
0                NaN
1          1000000.0
2           390000.0
3          3406159.0
4         21750000.0

   funding_total_usd
0                NaN
1           10000.00
2            3900.00
3           34061.59
4          217500.00
```

To solve your comma problem, please run this as your first command before you print. It will remove all your commas for the float values.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
```

Comment: I got this error "ValueError: Cannot specify ',' with 's'" when I tried this df['funding_total_usd'] = df.apply(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x['funding_total_usd']), axis=1)

Comment: I tried this code:for row in df1['funding_total_usd']:
    dt1 = str(row).replace (',','')    
    print (dt1)

Comment: I realize you are trying to divide the number by 100 to get the decimal value. Let me share additional info

Comment: Do you have any idea how to add "." before the last two digits to be every number as a "1234.45" instead of "123445"?

Comment: first do df['funding_total_usd'] = df['funding_total_usd']/100. That will give you the decimal place.

Comment: let me know the new inputs helped you with the formatting and decimal place.

Comment: I tried this code list1 = []

for row in df1['funding_total_usd']:
    dt1 = str(row).replace (',','')
    dt1 = int (dt1)/100
    list1.append (dt1)
    print (dt1)

Comment: can you do df['funding_total_usd'].dtypes and let me know if this is a string or int or float please? I think it is a float. If it is a float, why are you doing so many things. It is a simple divide

Comment: I tried to do what do advise me to do and this what I got dtype('O')

Comment: sorry, i should have asked you for this. I want to know if funding_total_usd is a float. To see if it is, there are a few ways to do it. Can you try this please `df.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])`  If the values of funding_total_usd comes thru, then you have a float column. So you can just do simple division as per my earlier response.